# Why does this C++ code actually compile and work?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code. Why does this work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int array = 4;
    cout << array[i] << endl; 
}
```

This compiles without warnings and errors and outputs 5.

Comment: Because Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @AndrewCheong what does this have to do with undefined behaviour?

Comment: @TartanLlama - Ah, from a quick glance I thought this was an issue of reading out of bounds memory, whose behavior I recall is undefined. Reading your marked duplicate now.

Comment: Isn't it because, `array` is not an array (or a pointer)?

Comment: @Leeor it doesn't matter that `array` is not aptly named, that indexing is well-defined.

Comment: Ah, I missed that `i` *is* an array. What a nasty piece of code.

Comment: Actually, this is not a question, but puzzle inherited from C (still interesting, though).